# Convert Gregorian Date to Julian

Tags: oracle, datetime, vbscript

Hi I am trying to create a function for Gregorian to Julian date & Julian to Gregorian so that i can use these in reports/queries/vbs scripts in the future without having to include this in everything moving forward. This is for an oracle database and the gregorian date format we are using is ddmmyyyy. I have tried to use the following below which returns todays julian date but am having no luck so far converting from greg to julian.

```
select sysdate, to_char(sysdate,'YDDD') "YDDD" from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has limited built-in support for Julian date:

`SELECT TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'J')) TO_JULIAN, TO_DATE (2457259, 'J') TO_GREGORIAN FROM DUAL`

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful link [here](http://www.jdelist.com/vb4/showthread.php/42369-Gregorian-(Normal)-to-Julian-Conversion-Oracle-Function) you can use.

Georgian to Julian

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DATE2JDE (yyyymmdd IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
v_jdedate NUMBER(6,0) := 0;

BEGIN
IF yyyymmdd BETWEEN 19000000 AND 28000000 THEN
v_jdedate := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(yyyymmdd,'YYYYMMDD'),'YY YYDDD'))-1900000;
ELSE
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid date in DATE2JDE - ' || yyyymmdd ||'.');
END IF;

RETURN(v_jdedate);

END;
```

Julian to Georgian

```
v_oracle_date := to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+1900000),'YYYYDDD')
v_char_year := to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+1900000),'YYYYDD D'),'YYYY')
v_char_month := to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+1900000),'YYYYDD D'),'MM')
v_char_day := to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+1900000),'YYYYDD D'),'DD')
v_num_year := to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+190000 0),'YYYYDDD'),'YYYY')
v_num_month := to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+190000 0),'YYYYDDD'),'MM')
v_num_day := to_number(to_char(to_date(to_char(v_JDEDate+190000 0),'YYYYDDD'),'DD')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these examples of conversion:

```
select  to_char('2017-06-24 13:27:14','YYYY-MM-DD','nls_calendar=persian') from dual
```

or this one

```
select  to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD','nls_calendar=persian') from dual
```

This work in oracle 12c works.